# How do I Upload Image via form to facebook using graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, upload

In regards to this post - 
[how to set a facebook profile picture using the graph api](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api/5431751#5431751)

How do I submit an image from a form field? what dies the realpath method do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is in example of posting an image to facebook using a form.[Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/)